JavaFX Button set to disable on click causes StackOverflowError
I have a ComboBox in which I store a list of labels and I've added an extra row in which i allow the user to write their own label and add it to the list.
Described combobox with the edition row on the bottom, the reload button is not relevant here.
This whole row is added programatically with the use of the ComboBoxListViewSkin.
Within this row is the Button in question - the "+Add" button, working in tandem with the TextField right next to it. It becomes enabled whenever the textfield's content is not blank and disables when it is, including right after submitting the newly created label.
Minimum Reproducible Example application class:
package org.example;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.skin.ComboBoxListViewSkin;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class App extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        ComboBox<String> comboBox = new ComboBox<>();
        ComboBoxListViewSkin<String> comboBoxListViewSkin = new ComboBoxListViewSkin<String>(comboBox) {
            private Button buttonAdd = new Button("+Add");

            private TextField textField = new TextField();
            private VBox pane = new VBox();
            {
                buttonAdd.setDisable(true);
                buttonAdd.setOnAction(event -> {
                    String text = textField.getText();
                    if (text.isBlank()) return;
                    comboBox.getItems().add(text);
                    textField.clear();
                    buttonAdd.setDisable(true);
                });
                textField.setOnKeyTyped(event -> {
                    if (textField.getText().isBlank())
                        buttonAdd.setDisable(true);
                    else buttonAdd.setDisable(false);
                });

                textField.setOnAction(event -> buttonAdd.fire());
            }

            @Override
            public Node getPopupContent() {
                Node defaultContent = super.getPopupContent();
                HBox hBox = new HBox();
                hBox.getChildren().addAll(buttonAdd, textField);
                HBox.setHgrow(textField, Priority.ALWAYS);
                defaultContent.setManaged(true);
                pane.getChildren().setAll(defaultContent, hBox);
                return pane;
            }
        };
        comboBox.setSkin(comboBoxListViewSkin);
        comboBox.setPrefWidth(400);
        comboBox.setPrefHeight(30);
        VBox vBox = new VBox(comboBox);

        Scene scene = new Scene(vBox, 400, 100);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static final void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}


And that's where the problem lies, whenever the label is submitted with this button it causes a StackOverflowError. This MRE made me notice that this only happens on the second and later additions, so perhaps it's some sort of 'editing during iteration' kind of issue?
I will note that the change is also correctly propagated into my app's data structure, the UI is updated accordingly and there do not seem to be any other issues with the program except for this error loop in the logs:
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at com.sun.glass.ui.Accessible$GetAttribute.run(Accessible.java:144)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.Accessible.lambda$getAttribute$0(Accessible.java:172)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:424)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.Accessible.getAttribute(Accessible.java:169)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinAccessible.sendNotification(WinAccessible.java:273)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinAccessible.sendNotification(WinAccessible.java:281)
// ...

The trace suggests it's a rendering/ui issue?
The troublemaker seems to be this buttonAdd.setDisable(true) at the end of the setOnAction lambda, as removing it has caused the error to not appear anymore.
I am not sure why this causes the issue.
I thought that perhaps calling the textField.clear() might trigger its own onAction and refire the button but that does not seem to be the case and neither does it seem to be stuck rerunning the button's onAction.

Edit:
This only seems to happen when using the button directly with a mouseclick and not when pressing Enter within the textfield (propagated buttonAdd.fire()).
I'm using JavaFX 19.0.2.1 on Windows 10 (22H2).

Which version of JavaFX are you using? Which platform? I cannot seem to reproduce the problem using JavaFX 23.0.1 on Windows 11 (though there does seem to be a visual glitch with the cell's "selected border" still being visible when the combo box collapses). No matter how many entries I add, how many times I enter text and delete it, which item I select, and so on, no SOE occurs. Though I notice some accessibility code is involved based on the stack trace you provided. Do you have any accessibility services active on your computer?

As an aside, on JavaFX 19+ you can simplify your disable-button-logic with just buttonAdd.disableProperty().bind(textField.textProperty().map(String::isBlank)). JavaFX 19 is when the map method was added. On older versions of JavaFX, you'd have to make use of something like Bindings::createBooleanBinding.

Or if you just want to test if the string is empty instead of blank, you can make use of StringExpression::isEmpty (note StringProperty inherits from StringExpression).

All of this keystroke checking on TextField seems to me to be a code smell. Just bind the "Default" property " of the Button to the "Focused" property of the TextField, and the "Disabled " property of the Button to the "Empty" property of the TextField's "Text" property.  Then hitting "Enter" in the non-brank TextField will fire the Button.

Assuming that anyone adding a value to the ComboBox would also want to select that item, why not just make the ComboBox editable and then add some code in the ComboBox action to add the selection to the list if it's not already there?

It's entirely possible that the SO error happens because this is implemented inside of the ComboBox skin, and somehow conflicts with the internal workings of the skin.

I also cannot reproduce this error. As well as the other code improvements, I'd note that creating a new HBox on every call to getPopupContent() is probably not a good idea; create and populate it once.

I would also not have one control (the text field) fire an event on another (the button). Just create a single event handler and pass it to both setOnAction(...) methods.

@Slaw JavaFX 19.0.2.1 on Windows 10 (latest), no accessibility features that i know of. The property binding does not fix the issue, nor do the other suggested improvements (though appreciated). With the binding i also arrive at just one onAction listener on the button and the issue persists.
I have also noticed that it only occurs when using the button directly (i.e. mouse click) and not via the propagated textfield action.
The problem however seems to stem from textField.clear().

@DaveB That's a great idea, not sure why i didn't think of it earlier (i think i had some issues with placing an 'add' button within the box itself, which was my idea at the time?) but I'll stay with this for now, if nothing else - for the sake of not leaving a dead question for future users :)

The issue persists on JavaFX 22.0.2, which seems to be the latest stable release not requiring JDK 21.

Subclassing the built in skins is fraught with danger, as you found.  The behavior and logic of the built in skins can change from release to release or platform to platform, breaking your app in non-intuitive ways.
